# how to print all the subfolders inside a folder c++ under ubuntu

Tags: c++, file, ubuntu, directory

I am new to c++/ubuntu. I have the following sittualtion: I want at every 2 seconds to read all the files(subfolders) from a folder and print them on the screen. If each subfolder has files I would also like to print those files too. In my sittuation I can only have a folder with subfolders that contains files.
Eg: folder primary-> subfolder 1 with: name.txt, age.txh; subfolder 2 with name.txt, age.txt.and so on. I would also like to specify THAT i do not know the total number of subfolders because it will increase or decrease dynamically.

1. How to create a thread for 2 second that will print the files from subfolders.
2. How to print the files from subfolders?

Can someone please print a c++ code example? THX! APPRECIATE A LOT!

Comment: Why do you want C++ to do this? Can't use `ls -R`?

Comment: Please note that [SO] is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just some toy you're putting together you might be suited with:

```sh
watch --interval=2 ls -laR
```

or

```
while true ; do sleep 2 ; ls -laR ; done
```

If you're really interested in writing this as an application, the better approach would be to use `nftw(3)` to walk over all directories and files periodically. Provide routines to do what you need for files and directories to `nftw(3)` and let someone else do all the hard work.

The best approach would use the `inotify(7)` interface to *watch* the directory and all subdirectories for *changes* to the file system. This avoids frequently re-reading the directories and file metadata that does not change between updates. This approach will require significantly less disk bandwidth and CPU. The downside is that `inotify(7)` is Linux-specific, and there is a maximum number of watches available. (524288 on my current system; it is tunable via `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`, so it could be higher or lower depending upon local configuration and other system uses of `inotify(7)`.)

Comment: how to use inotify for monitoring the sufolders?

Comment: You attach a new `inotify(7)` watch for every subfolder.

Comment: ls is not working.  receive permission denied

Comment: Obviously you do need permissions to read and traverse directories. Do you have those permissions?